# Как убрать ограничение fps в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Не получается снять лок фпс в игре. Почему-то именно в билде 30 фпс. При этом убирал вертикальную синхронизацию в настройках проекта, ограничивал фпс через `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;` При этом в предыдущем билде было стабильно 60 фпс... Даже не знаю что делать...

Comment: В коде самостоятельно не писали ограничения?

Comment: Нет, самостоятельно не писал никакие ограничения фпс.